# Microsoft Report Builder - use Jira data source?

Tags: sql-server, jira, business-intelligence, reportbuilder, rdl

I use Microsoft Report Builder to produce indicators (reports in .rdl format). They are based on pre-calculated data in an intermediate database.

We would also need to rely on Jira data, however I couldn't find a way to use Jira data sources. Is it possible ?

(I didn't have this problem with Power BI, however I wanted to go to Report Builder to keep costs down.)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to create SSRS reports with data coming from JIRA?

Comment: I am new to these technologies. Someone had indicated to me the possibility of making reports in RDL format and then publishing them in SSRS.
At the moment I am still at the first step with ReportBuilder to produce the RDL files. Since it allows me to connect to different sources (Oracle, etc ...) I was wondering about Jira.

Comment: I would like to include in my RDL files some Jira data, in addition to the Oracle data.

Comment: https://zappysys.com/blog/read-jira-data-in-ssrs-reports/

Comment: I would like to include in my RDL files some Jira data: from where you are getting the data ?

Comment: Thank you for the link. Data is computed and collected into an Oracle Database. So, RDL files contains queries from this intermediate database.